# Trying to connect Postman SocketIO to Flask API and get 400

Tags: flask, postman, flask-socketio

I implemented a Flask SocketIO server using **Flask-SocketIO 5.3.2** and it is working well when I test it using a JavaScript client even from different origin. But when I try to connect to the server using Postman SocketIO, I am getting **Error: Unexpected server response: 400** in Postman and Flask Server is logging SocketIO 400 Error. Attached are screenshots from both Postman Response and Server logs.

**Server Logs:**
[image]

**Postman Response:**
[image]

Comment: What is your CORS configuration? You may be getting this error because of CORS.

Comment: I configured it to accept requests from everywhere. There is also this line: **socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")**

Comment: Is there any proxy server behind your application?

Comment: No proxy server

Comment: @ValentineSean did you find any solution? im facing this exact one

Comment: @abdulwasey20 yes check the answer I wrote below

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that the flask built in development server was using polling whereas postman client was using websocket. So I configured websocket for the server using gevent and resolved the issue. You can get more information about this from this discussion [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/y5e4sh/connect_to_flasksocketio_through_postman_client/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), this is where I got the idea.

**Code Snippet:**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from gevent import pywsgi
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
socketio.init_app(app)

@socketio.on("message")
def message(data):
    print(data)
    socketio.emit("myevent", "EVENT DATA HERE...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pywsgi.WSGIServer(("", PORT_NUMBER), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler).serve_forever()
```

Run the app using the command below (Tested on Ubuntu only for app file named **app.py**):

```
python3 -m app
```